# What does CTRL-G do in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I know that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> finds usages of a particular element. However, if I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> then something similar happens, it appears usages are found, but it seems more of a subset.

Its not really clear to me exactly what <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on an element in Java does.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

```
Find **declarations** in workspace
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

```
Find **references** in workspace
```

If you want to change those,open `Windows->Preferences->General->Keys.` 
Now you can use the filter to find your shortcut and change its binding.

Comment: So...Ctrl-G = Decleration, Ctrl-Shft-G = Usages ?

Comment: I don't get it. Declarations (plural)? Would `Ctrl+G` ever find more than one answer ? Isn't that the same as holding `Ctrl` and clicking the item?

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu Good question.Exactly.Using plural in the sense declarations of Elements.Not multiple declarations of a single element :)

Comment: and what does ctrl + alt + g ??

Answer (score 1):

To find out in general what any keyboard shortcut does in Eclipse, go to Preferences | Keys. Type the combination in the Binding text box and you'll see its current binding.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice for the glory of preferences.

Comment: To be less cryptic: Ctrl+Shift+L displays a popup with a list of possible shortcuts.

Comment: And if you press that key twice you get directly to the Preferences Page to configure all Keys for all perspectives and commands.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to find the declaration of the field or method