# Java - Finding out all the places where the current class is being created

Tags: java, reflection

I'd like to check all the places where my class is being created - with the  new operator and with Reflection. How can I do it?

Comment: Programmaticly? Or through your IDE?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Any way is accepted. I looking towards developing my own plugin that uses it.

Comment: In Eclipse (CTRL+SHIFT+G): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231851/what-does-ctrl-g-do-in-eclipse

Comment: You can't reliably find where it is created reflectively, because there is always the potential to pick the class to instantiate at runtime.

Comment: Ok, thank you!! I think I came up to a conclusion on how to overcome the issue using the above Find References :)